# Where can I put a static file in Beaker notebook so that my HTML can find it?

Tags: beaker-notebook

Where can I put an image or other static file in Beaker so that my HTML can find it? And will this image work if I share the notebook with someone else?

Answer (score 1):

Put them in **~/.beaker/v1/web**, and then from your HTML and JS you can refer to it with **/user**. For example if you have an image at **~/.beaker/v1/web/foo.jpg** you can use it with **img src="/user/foo.jpg">**. See the [tutorial](https://pub.beakernotebook.com/#/publications/560c55c5-1ef7-41fa-ab8c-71b0b3aa68c3?fullscreen=true).

Note that if you do this, the images will not work if you share the notebook with someone else. We are planning on a better solution for this, see [Issue #430](https://github.com/twosigma/beaker-notebook/issues/430).